# ListPicker bind value always set to index and not valueField

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have this simple array categories being displayed on the html template. The issue is that when I select the item on the list, it sets the `book.category` to the index of the item on the ListPicker and not the specified valueField. I am not sure if this is the default behavior or I am missing something.

Array:

```js
public categories = [
        {id: 6, name: "Horror"},
        {id: 8, name: "Biography"},
        {id: 5, name: "Drama"},
        {id: 7, name: "Comedy"},
        {id: 2, name: "Fiction"}
    ];
```

HTML(Angular):

```html
<ListPicker [items]="categories" textField="name" valueField="id" 
       [(ngModel)]="book.category"></ListPicker>
```

Comment: looked into the document section of ``listPicker`` , why don't you use the ``index`` returned to pick the item from the ``categories`` ?

Comment: The model always works on selectedIndex with ListPicker, you can get the actual value by accessing the source at index, in controller `this.categories[this.book.category]` while saving / sending the value.

Comment: I was expecting that it gets assigned to the item id. It's not intuitive. Nativescript is weird, now I have to go look for a Checkbox plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the [ListPicker - NativeScript Docs page](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listpicker) and it looks like the missing thing is you are not implementing a handler for the `selectedIndexChange` event which would change your html element to the following:

```html
<ListPicker [items]="categories" textField="name" valueField="id" [(ngModel)]="book.category" (selectedIndexChange)="yourSelectedIndexChangeHandlerFunction($event)"></ListPicker>
```

and in your .ts file a function should be added, something like below:

```js
public yourSelectedIndexChangeHandlerFunction(args) {
    let picker = <ListPicker>args.object;
    this.id = picker.SelectedIndex; // assuming that your valuefield property is binding to this.id
}
```

Just play around with the code above and enjoy!

Comment: I did add that selectedIndexChange before but I was hoping that the model would get assigned to the item id and not the index.

Comment: you mean like `this.id = picker`? you can do that but you have to modify the declaration of id to the ListPicker class like `var id: ListPicker;`